# RInno fails with error 800A03EE expecting ')'

Tags: r

Running the executable from the example app (or my own app) for RInno from RStudio gives the above error on Win 10, Win 7, 32 bit or 64 bit architectures. This appears to be unresolved - maintainer can not reproduce. https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno/issues/44 Has anyone solved this or figured out how to reproduce?

```
install.packages("RInno")
require(RInno)
example_app(app_dir = "app")
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "app")
compile_iss()
```

R version 3.4.4